# Stop then restart submit() after ajax check

Tags: jquery, ajax

I asked a question [**[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2632970/return-false-for-parent-javascript-function)**] recently and it's just not providing me with an answer.  Here's what I want to do and you can see my first attempt at the link above:

1. User submits form
2. Stop default submit action
3. check to see if a similar entry exists in database

   4. **If it does**, display a notice asking them if they want to submit anyway and give an option to let them submit anyway (enable default action and submit it).
   5. **If it does not**, enable the default action on the form and let it submit

I'm at a loss.  Any help is appreciated.  Thanks gang.

**EDIT for Simeon**: Here is the code I'm using with your solution:

```
var forceSubmitForm = false;
$('#purchaser_contact').submit(function(){

  if(forceSubmitForm) return true;

  if( $("#id").val()=="" ){

    if( $("#fname").val()=='' || $("#city").val()=='' ){ alert('First Name and City are required fields. Please fill these in before continuing.'); return false; }

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax/contactSearch.php',
        data: ({ fname: $("#fname").val(), lname: $("#lname").val(), city: $("#city").val(), state: $("#state").val() }),
        success: function(d) {
            var obj = JSON.parse( d );
            if(obj.result != 0){
            $("#contactSearch").remove();
            $("#button-wrapper").before('<div id="contactSearch">'+obj.result+'</div>');
            $("#contactSearch").slideToggle('slow');                                
          } else {
            forceSubmitForm = true;
            $('#purchaser_contact').submit(); // Form will submit
          }
        }
      });   

      return false;

  } //END IF empty id

});
```

This won't work until the submit button is pushed a second time (ie, `$('#purchaser_contact').submit();` is not submitting the form).

**EDIT** This never did work for me but Simeon's answer is the closest and he claims it works in all major browsers so if it helps someone, great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution you are looking for.

```
var forceSubmitForm = false;
$('#myForm').submit(function(){
    if(forceSubmitForm) return true;
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function(data){
            if(data.entry != 'OK'){ // or whatever check
                forceSubmitForm = true;
                $('#myForm').submit(); // Form will submit
            }else{
                // Form will not be submitted
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

**EDIT**
To prove to myself that this methodology works, I just created a sample page with a form and a submit button. This worked fine in all major browsers:

```
$(function(){ // On DOM ready
    var forceSubmitForm = false;

    $('#purchaser_contact').live('submit', function() {
        if (forceSubmitForm){
            alert('submitting');
            return true;
        }

        // A callback function works in the same manner as a timeout

        setTimeout(function(){
            forceSubmitForm = true;
            $('#purchaser_contact').submit();
        }, 1500); // Submit after 1,5 seconds

        return false; // Do not submit immediately
    });
});
```

Comment: @Simeon this is close but requires a second click on the submit button if the ajax call doesn't return a match.  I want it to submit the form automatically if there's no match (which I think was your intention).

Comment: Of course you have to edit the code in the success function to fit your needs... I put a comment there: "or whatever check" and showed you how to do this. But if you don't have any knowledge of these matters I could write edit the answer, using your specifically current code in the other question.

Comment: The check isn't the issue.  Your solution doesn't work even if I apply my own check.  $('#myForm').submit() will NOT submit the form because it doesn't pass your `forceSubmitForm` value properly.

Comment: Yes it does. It sets forceSubmitForm = true, and that makes the form submit immediately when .submit() is called the next time. Look at the first row in the submit function, it returns true when called if the forceSubmitForm variable is set to true.

Comment: I so badly want it to work. Sadly it does not until a second click is made on the submit button.

Comment: Updated my question with the exact code using your solution @Simeon. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Have a look at my edited answer. Your code should work fine. If you still have no success, try inserting some alerts and tell me where the the code breaks. Are you using FireBug and Firefox? Please do, enable the console and make sure you get no errors.

Comment: Enabled console and also added a `alert('submitting after check');` where the submit is being forced.  I get the alert after check, and then i get the `alert('submitting');`.  Then it just sits. Everything works but the form refuses to submit.  Sigh. Ideas? No errors in console. My ajax call returns a '0' which is good as shown in console.

Answer (score 0):

You can process the form by adding a callback function to the submit event. If you want to stop the submit from going through you can preventDefault() on the event or return false.

```
$('form').submit(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();

   //do stuff, you can put your ajax call here
   ...

   if(fail) { return false; }
   else { return true; }
});
```

Comment: This isn't what was asked for.  The pass or fail functions need to happen as a result of the ajax success callback.

Answer (score 0):

Here's is jQuery example (not tested):

```
$(function() {
    $("#myForm").submit(function() {
        $.post(/* make AJAX request */ function() {
            if (/* similar entry does not exisits */) {
                 $("#myForm").data("allow-submit", true).submit();
            } else {
                 alert('NOT ALLOWED!');
            }
        });

        return $(this).data("allow-submit") || false; // prevent form submit if not allowed
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this option. the `.data()` isn't available to me until a second click on the submit button is made.

Comment: Can you see a way to avoid the second click on the submit button? I like this solution if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you want to run a function when the form is submitted and then short circuit the form action if your function is negative.  Something like this should do:

```
$("form#myForm").submit(function(){
    if(someCustomFunction()){//do the check
            event.preventDefault; //short circuit
            someOtherCustomFunction();//display your alternative

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me nuts and no solutions were working, it would either not submit the form or go into an infinite loop submitting the form. So I just turned the submit button into a regular button. Then submitted the form within the ajax loop. This means you don't have to worry about stopping the default action of the submit button as it's just a regular button.

```
<form id="loginForm" method="post" action="login.php">
<input type="text" name="username" id="username">
<input type="button" value="Log in" id="btnDoSomething">
</form>
```

And the Javascript/jQuery:

```
$("#btnDoSomething").click(function() {

    var request = $.ajax({
        data: {username: $("#username").val()},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
            // when response is returned do stuff then submit form
            // ...
            $("#loginForm").submit();
        },
        url: 'ajax-check-username.php'
    });
});
```

Also if the user hits the Enter key you'd want to do the ajax request then submit as well, so this code snippet is handy as well:

```
// If they hit the enter button, run the same method
$('#loginForm').bind('keypress', function(e)
{
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        $(this).find("#btnDoSomething").click();
    }
});
```

Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm necro-ing an old thread but I recently came across this problem and thought I'd throw in an answer for anyone else who stumbles upon this thread.  My solution was to make the `$.ajax` call synchronous.

This is what worked for me:

```
var formShouldSubmit = false;
$("form#my_form").bind("submit", function(){
     $.ajax({
        url: "my_form_validate.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
            if ( data.valid ){
                formShouldSubmit = true;
            }
            else{
                $("#error").html('Invalid entry');
            }
        },
        async: false,
        dataType: "json"
    });
    if ( !formShouldSubmit ){
        return false;
    }
});
```