# Jquery form.submit not working

Tags: jquery

I have the Code like this which checks code availability if code exists the form does not submit

i have the code which is not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Loading').hide();
            var min_chars = 3;  
            //result texts  
            var characters_error = 'Minimum amount of chars is 3';  
            var checking_html = 'Checking...';      


        $('#reality_form').submit(function(){

            if($('#realitycode').val().length < min_chars){
                $('#Info').html(characters_error);  
            }else{  
                //else show the cheking_text and run the function to check  
                    $('#Info').html(checking_html);  
                        var reltcode = $('#realitycode').val();  

                //use ajax to run the check  
                $.post("http://localhost/Testtt/wp-content/plugins/Realestate Redirection/check_realitycode_availablity.php", { realitycode: reltcode },

                 function(result){  
                    //if the result is 1  
                    if(result == 1){  
                        //show that the username is available
                        alert('hi');  
                        $('#Info').html(reltcode + ' is Available'); 

                    }else{  
                        alert('hello'); 
                        $('#Info').html(reltcode + ' is not Available');

                    } 

                }); 
           return false;    
            }

    });  

 }); 

</script>
<div class="wrap"> 
            <?php    echo "<h2>" . __( 'RealEstate Listing Options', 'oscimp_trdom' ) . "</h2>"; ?>
            <form action="" name="reality" method="post" id="reality_form">
            <input type="hidden" name="reality_hidden" value="Y">  
            Website Url:<input type="text" name="website_url" value="" />
            Listing Code: <input type="text" name="rlt_code" id="realitycode" />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
            <div id="Info"></div>
            <span id="Loading"><img src="http://localhost/Testtt/wp-content/plugins/Realestate Redirection/loader.gif" alt="" /></span>

            </form>
</div>
```

As i look on console the Ajax url becomes error but when i use for `realitycode keyup()` function then Ajax works properly. i want form should not get submit if any error. but form is submitting in every case
Please help

Comment: your return false/true is inside inner function.so it can not return false for submit function for preventing it from submmiting.

Comment: i have posted the answer.try and check if that help?

Comment: when i put it as said after Ajax then it stopped in every case    `code` $.post("http://localhost/Testtt/wp-content/plugins/Realestate Redirection/check_realitycode_availablity.php", { realitycode: reltcode },
     
     function(result){  
     //if the result is 1  
     if(result == 1){  
      //show that the username is available
      alert('hi');  
      $('#Info').html(reltcode + ' is Available'); 
       
     }else{  
      alert('hello'); 
      $('#Info').html(reltcode + ' is not Available');
      
     } 
     
    }); 
     return false;  `code`

Comment: can you post the edited code in your question?

Comment: i just edited the code & pasted

Comment: i mean post the code in code section.it is not readable here.

Comment: & posted back to Question again

Comment: you haven't applied my changes to your code!

Comment: i have edited whole your script block.try it...

Comment: i have edited it again and maybe for last time.check it.good luck.

Comment: I remember a jquery bug when using .submit() and having the name-Attribute of input type="submit" set to "submit".

Answer (score 2):

Use the .click event instead of submit. Then if the form is valid, call submit yourself in code.

Answer (score 1):

> i want form should not get submit if any error. but form is
>   submitting in every case Please help

Put `return false` at the ***end*** of your `$('#reality_form').submit()` function:

```
$('#reality_form').submit(function(){
   // your other code
   return false;
});
```

Comment: it gets stop now in everycase when i put `code` return false; `code` in end of function as said can you show through code where to put

Answer (score 0):

make following change to your code:

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
   var validated = false;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#Loading').hide();
                var min_chars = 3;  
                //result texts  
                var characters_error = 'Minimum amount of chars is 3';  
                var checking_html = 'Checking...';      


            $('#reality_form').submit(function(){
                if(validated)
                    return true;
                if($('#realitycode').val().length < min_chars){
                    $('#Info').html(characters_error);  
                }else{  
                    //else show the cheking_text and run the function to check  
                        $('#Info').html(checking_html);  
                            var reltcode = $('#realitycode').val();                   

                    //use ajax to run the check  
                    $.post("http://localhost/Testtt/wp-content/plugins/Realestate Redirection/check_realitycode_availablity.php", { realitycode: reltcode },

                     function(result){  
                        //if the result is 1  
                        if(result == 1){  
                            //show that the username is available
                            alert('hi');  
                            $('#Info').html(reltcode + ' is Available'); 
                            //do nothing

                        }else{  
                            alert('hello'); 
                            $('#Info').html(reltcode + ' is not Available');
                            validated = true;
                            $('#reality_form').submit();
                        }   
                    }); 
                  return false;    
                }

        });      

     }); 

    </script>
```

Comment: solution inferred from this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2637985/stop-then-restart-submit-after-ajax-check

Answer (score 0):

The other way to prevent from submitting is using the following code:

```
$('#reality_form').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
```

In jQuery each handler receives event object as the first parameter and this object has method `prevetDefault()` which suppresses the default behaviour. It could be used with any kind of event, such as `click` on `<a>` element.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the same problem.
The solution is...

```
Dont use name="submit"
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />

Instead
<input type="submit" name="anyOtherName" value="submit" />
```